# external fact not available at very first puppet run

Tags: puppet, hiera, facter

**Introduction:**

We are using puppet to configure the nodes via a custom fact which is then referenced in hiera. The fact can either reside in the golden image in /etc/facter/fact.d/ or via pluginsync (makes no difference, tested both)

**Versions:**

```
dpkg -l|grep puppet
hi  facter                             1.7.5-1puppetlabs1        amd64        Ruby module for collecting simple facts about a host operating system
hi  hiera                              1.3.4-1puppetlabs1        all          A simple     pluggable Hierarchical Database.
hi  puppet                             3.4.3-1puppetlabs1        all          Centralized configuration management - agent startup and compatibility scripts
hi  puppet-common                      3.4.3-1puppetlabs1        all          Centralized configuration management
```

**The setup is simple:**

Puppetmaster:

```
cat hiera.yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "aws/%{::aws_cluster}"

/etc/puppet/hieradata/aws/web.json
```

EC2 Node:

```
cat /etc/facter/facts.d/ec_cluster.sh
echo 'aws_cluster=web'
```

So there is this golden ec2 image including the fact aws_cluster. This is referenced in hiera and specifies the classes and configurations to make.

**Problem:**

When we boot the instance and enable autosigning the first run will not have the $aws_cluster present on the client side. So it will fail (which makes sense) saying

```
puppet-agent[2163]: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find data item classes in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:33 on node ip-172-31-35-221.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

When the puppet agent is restarted, everything works as expected. Any hints on this?

Our guess is:

- has it something to do with certificate generation?
- what happens the very first run?
- is it different if we start it by hand /etc/init.d/puppet start than over init?

**Update:**

when trying to start it over /etc/rc.local it fails too. So there has to be a difference between interactive and non interactive runs. are there special enviroment variables which have to be set?

Comment: btw, this seems to work when we call the agent manually "puppet agent -t"

Comment: Interesting - there might kind of a race between pluginsync and hierarchy initialisation. Facts that are delivered using `pluginsync` **are** available during the first agent run, at least on the manifest level. If Hiera can fail for this, that may actually be a bug.

Comment: when trying to start it over /etc/rc.local it fails too. So there has to be a difference between interactive and non interactive runs. are there special enviroment variables which have to be set?

Comment: To clarify: Does this break after every reboot, or only right after provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry guys, we were on the wrong track.

After further debugging and logging output from rc.local from facter -p, we have seen that our external fact is requiring the aws credentials for the script to run successfully. This is automatically sourced when you are logged in as root, but is not when you run it at boot time.

So exporting the env parameters for the aws credentials solved the case.

the information that is not working with plan key value pair must have been wrong while debugging. sry

**tl;dr: it was not a puppet bug / problem**